# Deleting repeating values in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySql table which is populating daily with price values. Each day it records an entry even if the price hasn't changed. I want to delete some rows that repeat too much. I want to keep the first price and the last price before there is a price change.

**Example 1)**

```
   id name     price date
    1 Product1 $6 13/07/2017
    2 Product1 $6 14/07/2017
    3 Product1 $6 15/07/2017
    4 Product1 $7 16/07/2017
    5 Product1 $6 17/07/2017
    6 Product1 $6 18/07/2017
    7 Product1 $6 19/07/2017
```

From that list records with id 2 and 6 should be deleted with the following result:

```
   id name     price date
    1 Product1 $6 13/07/2017
    3 Product1 $6 15/07/2017
    4 Product1 $7 16/07/2017
    5 Product1 $6 17/07/2017
    7 Product1 $6 19/07/2017
```

**Example 2)**

```
   id name     price date
    1 Product1 $6 13/07/2017
    2 Product1 $6 14/07/2017
    3 Product1 $6 15/07/2017
    4 Product1 $6 16/07/2017
    5 Product1 $6 17/07/2017
    6 Product1 $6 18/07/2017
    7 Product1 $6 19/07/2017
```

Here there is no price change so I can delete all records from 2 to 6:

```
   id name     price date
    1 Product1 $6 13/07/2017
    7 Product1 $6 19/07/2017
```

Id is not supposed to be one incremental and also date is not updated on daily basis.

Comment: What about record 4?

Comment: And you're using MySQL, right?

Comment: yes i am using MySQL

Comment: i want to keep record 4

Comment: 4 is between 2 and 6, so you have to make up your mind

Comment: but it has different price

Comment: Either your comment is wrong, or the statements you make in your question are wrong. Both things cannot be right - unless you're Donald Trump.

Comment: And you need to keep #3 in the first example so that "same price before there is a price change".

Comment: yes that is what i want. I want to keep 1,3,4,5,7 from first example. I want to keep the first and last prices before there is change in price, and it should not matter whether that price occurs again.

Comment: Please add the information in your last comment to your question (as a detail to your first example, as currently that example does not make sense with the sentence directly below it. Since you want "to get precise answer", your question should be precise too). It would also be useful to not only describe it, but to actually add the expected result (as rows). Please use the date format you are actually using. "13/07/2017" is not a valid date in mysql, so if it is stored in that way (a varchar), the query would need to transform it into a date first (which would make the query a lot slower).

Comment: Why do you want to keep the last record in each grouping? if you assume that each price continues until the next price record then you just need to record a single record per price change. For first example: just keep rows 1, 4, and 5; and for second example just keep row 1. Would that work for your needs?

Comment: Is the column `Id` fictive? I mean you use this column just for row numbering and clarifying, but you don't have this column in the table.

Comment: The trouble is that your problem is fundamentally unsuited to SQL. It can be but the code will indeed be complex or will use extra procedural features of MySQL.

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar i.e. I don't think it will get much simpler than https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870213/2772719

Comment: Is the `Id` column unique?

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar You did not select an answer for the bounty; I am confident that this solves your problem. Lmk if you need clarification https://stackoverflow.com/a/45893303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the second answer I've submitted for this question, but I think I've finally got it this time:

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id_to_delete
    FROM (
        SELECT
            t0.id AS id_to_delete,
            t0.price,
            (
                SELECT t1.price
                FROM products AS t1
                WHERE (t0.date < t1.date)
                    AND (t0.name = t1.name)
                ORDER BY t1.date ASC
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS next_price,
            (
                SELECT t2.price
                FROM products AS t2
                WHERE (t0.date > t2.date)
                    AND (t0.name = t2.name)
                ORDER BY t2.date DESC
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS prev_price
        FROM products AS t0
        HAVING (price = next_price) AND (price = prev_price)
    ) AS t
)
```

This is a modified version of the answer from @vadim_hr.

Edit: Below is a different query that filters on `JOIN` instead of subquery.  `JOIN` may be faster than the former query (above) for large datasets, but I'll leave the performance testing up to you.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee0655/8

```
SELECT M.id as id_to_delete
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        (@j := @j + 1) AS j
    FROM
    (SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC, date ASC) AS mmm
    JOIN
    (SELECT @j := 1) AS mm
) AS M     -- the middle table
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        *,
        (@i := @i + 1) AS i
    FROM
    (SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC, date ASC) AS lll
    JOIN
    (SELECT @i := 0) AS ll
) AS L     -- the left table
ON M.j = L.i
    AND M.name = L.name
    AND M.price = L.price
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        *,
        (@k := @k + 1) AS k
    FROM
    (SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC, date ASC) AS rrr
    JOIN
    (SELECT @k := 2) AS rr
) AS R     -- the right table
ON M.j = R.k
    AND M.name = R.name
    AND M.price = R.price
```

Both queries accomplish the same end, and they both assume that rows are unique per `name` and `date` (as explained in the comment below).

Comment: your query is ok and has more powerful optimization potential. but if the column `date` is not unique ...

Comment: Yes I'd thought about that, but OP needs to provide more info if that is the case, to know how to handle 1 of 2 scenarios: (1) non-unique date but with only one price per product per date, in this case query can be updated to delete the duplicated prices, or (2) non-unique date with multiple prices per product per date, in this case OP must tell us how to handle non-distinct intraday prices. My suggestion is to slap a `UNIQUE INDEX(name, date)` on the products table, but either way OP must provide input if date is not unique  per product.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with some creative self-join logic.

Think of three hypothetical rows in the table.

- Row a you want to keep.
- Row b has the same product name and price, and a date 1 day after a. You want to delete this.
- Row c has the same product name and price, and a date 1 day after b. You want to keep this.

So if you can do a self-join to match these three rows, then delete row b.

```
DELETE b FROM MyTable AS a 
JOIN MyTable AS b ON a.name=b.name AND a.price=b.price AND a.date=b.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
JOIN MyTable AS c ON b.name=c.name AND b.price=c.price AND b.date=c.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

This works even if there are multiple rows that fit the conditions for row b. It'll delete the first one, and then continue to delete subsequent rows that also fit the conditions.

This works if you use the `DATE` data type and store your dates as 'YYYY-MM-DD', not 'DD-MM-YYYY'. You should do this anyway.

Comment: date is not specific to be one day

Comment: in the first example that i provided i only want to delete 2nd and 6th record from the table, because the price is repeating for the same product.

Answer (score 3):

You want to delete the rows where the product name and price are the same as the rows with the date plus/minus one day.

```
DELETE row_mid
FROM 
  record_table AS row_mid
  JOIN record_table AS row_prev
  JOIN record_table AS row_next
WHERE
  row_mid.name = row_prev.name 
  AND row_mid.price = row_prev.price
  AND row_mid.date = DATE_SUB(row_prev.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND row_mid.name = row_next.name
  AND row_mid.price = row_next.price
  AND row_mid.date = DATE_ADD(row_next.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: I created an sqlfiddle that demonstrates this working at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81e772/1

Comment: This relies on the date intervals being exactly 1 day, which OP said is *not* the case.

Answer (score 3):

Is your MySQL new enough to support CTE?  This is a pretty interesting problem I've seen with date scheduling.  The code always looks awkward.  To check the results without a delete you can switch the comment mark with the select and delete and comment out the t.[Name] is null line.

WITH

```
cte AS  (
        SELECT a.ID
            , a.[Name]
            , a.[Date]
            , a.Price
            , NextDate = max(npc.[Date])    -- Next Price change
            , PrevDate = max(lpc.[Date])    -- Next Price change
        FROM    yourTable as a  -- Base Table
            LEFT JOIN
                yourTable as npc    -- Looking for Next Price Change
            ON a.[Name] = npc.[Name]
                and a.[Date] < npc.[Date]
                and a.Price <> npc.Price
            LEFT JOIN
                yourTable as lpc    -- Looking for Last Price Change
            ON a.[Name] = lpc.[Name]
                and a.[Date] > lpc.[Date]
                and a.Price <> lpc.Price
        GROUP BY a.ID, a.[Name], a.[Date], a.Price
    ) 

----SELECT f.*, [Check] = CASE WHEN t.[Name] is null THEN 'DELETE' ELSE '' END
DELETE f
FROM 
        yourTable as f
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT [Name], [GoodDate] = Max([Date])
            FROM cte
            GROUP BY [Name], PrevDate
            UNION
            SELECT [Name], [GoodDate] = Min([Date])
            FROM cte
            GROUP BY [Name], PrevDate
            UNION
            SELECT [Name], [GoodDate] = Max([Date])
            FROM cte
            GROUP BY [Name], NextDate
            UNION
            SELECT [Name], [GoodDate] = Min([Date])
            FROM cte
            GROUP BY [Name], NextDate
        ) as t
    ON t.[Name] = f.[Name] and t.[GoodDate] = f.[Date]
WHERE t.[Name] is null
--ORDER BY f.[Name], f.[Date]
```

Comment: This problem can be solved simpler with a self-join, see a couple of the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect `prev Id` and `next Id`, then select rows for deletion:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
      *,
      (SELECT next_id.id 
       FROM a next_id 
       WHERE next_id.id > current.id 
       ORDER BY next_id.id ASC LIMIT 1) as next_id,
      (SELECT prev_id.id 
       FROM a prev_id 
       WHERE prev_id.id < current.id 
       ORDER BY prev_id.id DESC LIMIT 1) as prev_id 
   FROM a current) t
WHERE 
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM a next 
           WHERE next.name = t.name AND t.price = next.price AND next.id=t.next_id) 
   AND
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM a prev 
           WHERE prev.name = t.name AND t.price = prev.price AND prev.id=t.prev_id)
```

I tested this queries on both of your examples. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40383/1).

**UPDATE**. If the `Id` column is not unique then the logic must be corrected from `prev Id`+`next Id` to `prev Date`+`next Date`. Anyway general concept will stay the same. Query will looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
      *,
      (SELECT next_date.date 
       FROM a next_date 
       WHERE next_date.date > current.date AND next_date.name = current.name
       ORDER BY next_date.date ASC LIMIT 1) as next_date,
      (SELECT prev_date.date
       FROM a prev_date 
       WHERE prev_date.date < current.date AND prev_date.name = current.name
       ORDER BY prev_date.date DESC LIMIT 1) as prev_date
   FROM a current) t
WHERE 
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM a next 
           WHERE next.name = t.name AND t.price = next.price AND next.date=t.next_date) 
   AND
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM a prev 
           WHERE prev.name = t.name AND t.price = prev.price AND prev.date=t.prev_date)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ebb02/1) for second query.

Comment: the Id is not supposed to be one incremental each time.

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar thanks for the comment. I updated my query.

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar ok. now it is not required `Id` to be one incremental.

Comment: the query is 100% working, I don't know why you guys downvoted it. So please explain whats wrong. I don't optimize the query because I don't know anything about indexes in the table...

Comment: It isn't clear how this solves the problem. From this query output how can we infer that ids 2 and 6 are to be deleted?

Comment: @Adamantish this query shows the rows with must be deleted (rows 2 and 6). did you try to run this query? you can replace `select * from` with `delete from` .

Comment: @vadim_hr It produces many more rows than that at least judging from the SQL fiddle.

Comment: @Adamantish you are wrong. my testing table contains much more rows that MUST be deleted. if you will see only 2 and 6, then correct my testing table (delete rows with is not from example below).

Comment: You need to change the next/prev id select to order by date instead of id, but otherwise I think your answer is the right approach

Comment: @user2426679 You are right. Moreover we don't know anything about column `Id`. if `Id` is not unique, then the logic must be corrected from `prev id`+`next id` to `prev date` and `next date`. I updated my answer because of this.

Comment: @vadim_hr yes, but I think there is more refinements still.  See my new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45893303

Answer (score 2):

all of your data is repeated, witch one do you want to keep? your explanation is confusing.

you can save oldest data with same price and delete other :

```
with Ranked as (
select  name, price, date,
    dense_rank() 
    over (partition by name, price, date 
order by date desc) as DupeCount
from    Your_table P
)
delete  R
from    Ranked R
where   R.DupeCount <> 1
```

Comment: It's easy. I provided the sample table schema. you can see the price is repeating multiple time

Comment: try the query above.

Comment: FWIW, MySQL doesn't support CTE syntax until 8.0.1, and it doesn't support window functions like dense_rank() until 8.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

Well i cannot write the exact code for your scenario but you can write a Function\Procedure and follow this pseudo code

```
r = allrows
tobeDeleted = []
unique = []
for (var i=0;i<rows.length; i++){
    unique.push(rows[i]->id);
    dd = true;
    while (dd){
        if ((rows[i]->price == rows[i+1]->price) AND (rows[i]->name == rows[i+1]->price)){
            tobeDeleted.push(rows[i]->id);
            i++;
        }else{
            dd= false;
        }
    }
}

//tobeDeleted contains ids of rows to be deleted
//
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query ,hope it helps you.

**(I don't have mysql , I've tried to convert the syntax to my sql-- so I'm sorry if any syntax error.)**

**(I've tested it on sqlserver with random dates and different products ,it works well and get the result you want)**

```
/* get the data grouped by name with NewField continousDate to create continous dates for every product depends on the order of date
then save it to temporary table called tempWithContinousDate*/

CREATE TEMPORARY Table tempWithContinousDate Table  (id INT,name varchar(50),price DECIMAL(12,2),date DATE,continousDate DATE)

insert into tempWithContinousDate(id,name,price,date,continousDate)
select id,name,price,date,Date_Add(minimumDate,INTERVAL rn DAY)ContinousDate
from(
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.price,t1.date,min(t2.Date)minimumDate,count(*) rn
          from 
             (select id,name,price,date from yourTable) t1
          inner join 
            (select id,name,price,date from yourTable) t2 
          on t1.name=t2.name and t1.date>=t2.date
 group by t1.id,t1.name,t1.price,t1.date
 ) t




/* get the data grouped by name and price with NewField GroupDate to group every continous dates 
then save it to temporary table called tempData*/
CREATE TEMPORARY Table tempData (id INT,name varchar(50),price DECIMAL(12,2),date DATE,groupDate DATE)

insert into tempData(id,name,price,date,groupDate)
select id,name,price,date,DATE_SUB(continousDate, INTERVAL rowNumber DAY) groupDate
from(
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.price,t1.date,t1.continousDate,count(*) rowNumber
          from 
             (select id,name,price,date,continousDate from tempWithContinousDate) t1
          inner join 
            (select id,name,price,date,continousDate from tempWithContinousDate) t2 
          on t1.name=t2.name and t1.price=t2.price and t1.date>=t2.date
 group by t1.id,t1.name,t1.price,t1.date,t1.continousDate
 ) t



 /*select * from yourTable where id  in*/
 delete from yourTable where id not in
(select id from 
 (

/* query to order every continous data asscending using the date field */
select firstData.id,firstData.name,firstData.price,firstData.date,count(*) rn 
from  tempData firstData
left join  tempData secondData
on firstData.name=secondData.name and firstData.price=secondData.price and firstData.groupDate=secondData.groupDate
and firstData.date>=secondData.date
group by firstData.id,firstData.name,firstData.price,firstData.date


/* query to order every continous data  Descending using the date field */
union all
select firstData.id,firstData.name,firstData.price,firstData.date,count(*) rn 
from  tempData firstData
left join  tempData secondData
on firstData.name=secondData.name and firstData.price=secondData.price and firstData.groupDate=secondData.groupDate
and firstData.date<=secondData.date
group by firstData.id,firstData.name,firstData.price,firstData.date

 )allData where rn=1  

)
```

Comment: It deletes all the prices of same value and keep only one. But that is not my requirement. In my example i told that i need to delete only 2 and 6 values record

Comment: I've edited the query , hope it match your requirement

Comment: It delets 2,3,5,6 values form the table but i want to delete i want to keep 1,3,5 and 7 id values

Comment: any value between 1 and 3 and 5 and 7 should be deleted with same price

Comment: My query keep first and last record  with the same price, do you want to keep the odd ids  or what? , I didn't understand.

Comment: Well to clearify   pirce value from id 1 to 3 are same  for one product and then for id 4 it changes and from id 5 to 7 it repeats again. I want to delete records between 1 and 3 and 5 and 7. in the end the ids would be 1,3,4,5,7 as the output.

Comment: I've edited the query , I've tested it using your sample data and it works.

Comment: I could imagine this quite creative approach working if there were only one product and you could reliably say there was a price entry for every single day in the real table. Otherwise it's a very risky proposition for deleting data.

Comment: Can you provide a real sample with two products or more and the key you use for ordering the data

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar  I've edited the query after testing ,it works well with different products and different dates , hope it helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have to ask ourselves, when do we have to delete a record?

**Answer:** A record can be deleted,

- if there exists another record, with the same name, with the same price, and an earlier date, while there is no record with the same name, with another price in between the both dates.

  and
- if there exists another record, with the same name, with the same price, and a later date, while there is no record with the same name, with another price in between the both dates.

Putting both requirements into SQL results in the following:

```
DELETE FROM PriceTable t
WHERE 
  EXISTS ( SELECT *
           FROM PriceTable tmp1 
           WHERE t.name  = tmp1.name  AND 
                 t.price = tmp1.price AND 
                 t.date  > tmp1.date  AND
                 NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM PriceTable tmp2
                             WHERE t.name    = tmp2.name  AND 
                                   t.price  != tmp2.price AND 
                                   t.date    > tmp2.date  AND 
                                   tmp1.date < tmp2.date 
                            )
         )
  AND
  EXISTS ( SELECT *
           FROM PriceTable tmp1 
           WHERE t.name  = tmp1.name  AND 
                 t.price = tmp1.price AND 
                 t.date  < tmp1.date  AND
                 NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM PriceTable tmp2
                             WHERE t.name    = tmp2.name  AND 
                                   t.price  != tmp2.price AND 
                                   t.date    < tmp2.date  AND 
                                   tmp1.date > tmp2.date 
                            ) 
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below piece of code. Let me know if it is working.

```
DELETE FROM record_table
WHERE id NOT IN (
    (SELECT MIN(id) FROM record_table GROUP BY name, price),
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM record_table GROUP BY name, price)
)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I think this would not work because it would group any rows with the same name and price, not just those in contiguous groups. So in the first example it would delete rows 2, 3, 5, and 6.

Comment: Please see my output that i want. I don't want to delte 3 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`

```
DELETE FROM test t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM test t2 
  WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND t1.price = t2.price AND t1.day = DATE_SUB(t2.DAY, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AND
EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM test t3 
  WHERE t1.name = t3.name AND t1.price = t3.price AND t1.day = DATE_ADD(t3.DAY, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
```

or `IN` construct to solve your problem

```
DELETE FROM test t1
WHERE t1.day IN (
  SELECT DATE_SUB(t2.day, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  FROM test t2 
  WHERE t1.NAME = t2.NAME AND t1.price = t2.price
) AND t1.day IN (
  SELECT DATE_ADD(t3.day, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  FROM test t3 
  WHERE t1.NAME = t3.NAME AND t1.price = t3.price
)
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad68f/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logic below:

1. rank by price
2. group by id, name, price
3. get min date
4. get max date

Following the query and fiddle example:

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;

select distinct
  `name`,
  `price`,
  `date`
from 
(
  (
  select 
    id,
    name,
    price,
    CASE
      WHEN @prev_value = price THEN @rank_count
      WHEN @prev_value := price THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
    END AS rank,
    min(`date`) as `date`
  from 
    `prices`
   group by 
     `name`, 
     `price`, 
     `rank`
   )
   union distinct
   (
   select 
    id,
    name,
    price,
    CASE
      WHEN @prev_value = price THEN @rank_count
      WHEN @prev_value := price THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
    END AS rank,
    max(`date`) as `date`
  from 
    `prices`
   group by 
     `name`, 
     `price`, 
     `rank`
  )
  order by `id`, `date`
) as `result`
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5519b/67)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: after further consideration, it appears that it's not possible to solve this problem with user defined variable trickery (take note of the other solutions using these).  While I think the below solution will "most likely work 99% of the time," MySQL does not guarantee the order of variable evaluation: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891422/mysql-functions-internal-execution-order#comment78744035_45891422) and [link 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html#c12908).

Original answer:

(I am working under the assumptions that `products.name` is defined as `NOT NULL` and both `products.id` and `products.price` are not negative [can provide a simple patch if handling negatives, too]).

The query:

```
SET
    @one_prior_id := NULL,
    @one_prior_price := NULL,
    @one_prior_name := NULL,
    @two_prior_id := NULL,
    @two_prior_price := NULL,
    @two_prior_name := NULL
;

SELECT @two_prior_id AS id_to_delete
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM products
    ORDER BY name, date
) AS t
WHERE IF(
    (
        (name  = @one_prior_name)
        AND
        (name  = @two_prior_name)
        AND
        (price = @one_prior_price)
        AND
        (price = @two_prior_price)
    ), (
        GREATEST(
            1,
            IFNULL(@two_prior_id := @one_prior_id, 0),
            IFNULL(@two_prior_price := @one_prior_price, 0),
            LENGTH(IFNULL(@two_prior_name := @one_prior_name, 0)),
            IFNULL(@one_prior_id := id, 0),
            IFNULL(@one_prior_price := price, 0),
            LENGTH(IFNULL(@one_prior_name := name, 0))
        )
    ), (
        LEAST(
            0,
            IFNULL(@two_prior_id := @one_prior_id, 0),
            IFNULL(@two_prior_price := @one_prior_price, 0),
            LENGTH(IFNULL(@two_prior_name := @one_prior_name, 0)),
            IFNULL(@one_prior_id := id, 0),
            IFNULL(@one_prior_price := price, 0),
            LENGTH(IFNULL(@one_prior_name := name, 0))
        )
    )
)
```

The query's return, based on your "Example 1:"

```
+--------------+
| id_to_delete |
+--------------+
|            2 |
|            6 |
+--------------+
```

The query's return, based on your "Example 2:"

```
+--------------+
| id_to_delete |
+--------------+
|            2 |
|            3 |
|            4 |
|            5 |
|            6 |
+--------------+
```

How the query works:

- Do a simple 'partitioning' of the `products` table via ORDER BY
- Loop over the ordered result set, tracking 2 sets of variables: the 1st set to hold the price and name of the 'one prior' row (the 'one prior' row being directly above the current row) and the 2nd set of variables to hold the 'two prior' row (the 'two prior' row being directly above the 'one prior' row).
- The `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are identical except that the former returns a value that will evaluate to true for the `IF` and the latter will evaluate to false.  The real point of these functions is to update our loop variables.
- See [this](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/) for more info regarding variable updating within subqueries.

The actual DELETE:

```
SET
    @one_prior_id := NULL,
    @one_prior_price := NULL,
    @one_prior_name := NULL,
    @two_prior_id := NULL,
    @two_prior_price := NULL,
    @two_prior_name := NULL
;

DELETE FROM products WHERE id IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT @two_prior_id AS id_to_delete
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM products
            ORDER BY name, date
        ) AS t1
        WHERE IF(
            (
                (name  = @one_prior_name)
                AND
                (name  = @two_prior_name)
                AND
                (price = @one_prior_price)
                AND
                (price = @two_prior_price)
            ), (
                GREATEST(
                    1,
                    IFNULL(@two_prior_id := @one_prior_id, 0),
                    IFNULL(@two_prior_price := @one_prior_price, 0),
                    LENGTH(IFNULL(@two_prior_name := @one_prior_name, 0)),
                    IFNULL(@one_prior_id := id, 0),
                    IFNULL(@one_prior_price := price, 0),
                    LENGTH(IFNULL(@one_prior_name := name, 0))
                )
            ), (
                LEAST(
                    0,
                    IFNULL(@two_prior_id := @one_prior_id, 0),
                    IFNULL(@two_prior_price := @one_prior_price, 0),
                    LENGTH(IFNULL(@two_prior_name := @one_prior_name, 0)),
                    IFNULL(@one_prior_id := id, 0),
                    IFNULL(@one_prior_price := price, 0),
                    LENGTH(IFNULL(@one_prior_name := name, 0))
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS t2
)
```

**Important Note**

See how the above delete query does 2 inner selects?  Make sure that you include this, otherwise you will unintentionally delete the last row!  Try executing without the `SELECT (...) AS t2` to see what I mean.